# Maya/Unity - See through models

Tags: unity, textures, maya, rigging

I've recently modeled my character inside Maya; here's an image. The first thing I noticed whilst creating my model is that the models could be seen through *source 1*, after doing a little research people stated that it was a graphical bug in Maya. However, once imported into Unity the same effect occurs.

**Therefore, my Question is: How can I fix this inside Maya or Unity?**

To prove that my UV map doesn't contain a low opacity texture see the second image below:

[image: Source 1]
[image: Source 2]

Answer (score 1):

**I FINALLY FIXED IT**

Being a scrub to the Maya Hyper-shade panel. I did a load of research and found out it was due to my file type of the texture; I used a PNG and it caused the model to conflict with it's alpha opacity causing it to, well, be translucent. Thank you for all the feedback and I hope this solves anyone else's problems in Maya.

All opaque <3

[image]